# Google is not defined (api maps error)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After being reading some time... I wanted to start use the Google Maps API for Javascript. I got the key on their website, I tried many ways to create maps but now, I want to create a map by a previous "location" so first, I use the Geocoder.geocode() and then I create the map, last night it was working okey.

So, I decided to start use overlays (Markers) in these maps but I don't know **I'm getting the Uncaught error: google is not defined.**

I read a bit about it and i know most of times is about asynchronous problem but, I still don't know how fix it, here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>

  </head>


  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeaWLxSHFEdwWEVVYajslt7R9eP0ZpLXQ&callback=initMap"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var sLocation = "Castillejos 265 Barcelona";
        var sLocationToSearch =sLocation.split(' ').join('+');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+ sLocationToSearch +'&key=AIzaSyAeaWLxSHFEdwWEVVYajslt7R9eP0ZpLXQ',

            success: function(res){
                // ParseFloat the <latitud> and <longitud>
                //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(trader.geo.lat),parseFloat(trader.geo.lon));

                initMap(res.results[0].geometry.location);
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        function initMap(oLatlng){
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: oLatlng,
              zoom: 15
            });
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**thanks a lot for your help**

Comment: Every time someone has problem like this, it is always because of `async`, `defer` and `&callback=initMap` in script tag. Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call javascript after page is loaded by using window.onload

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map
        {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

</head>


<body>

<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAeaWLxSHFEdwWEVVYajslt7R9eP0ZpLXQ&callback=initMap"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var sLocation = "Castillejos 265 Barcelona";
        var sLocationToSearch = sLocation.split(' ').join('+');

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + sLocationToSearch + '&key=AIzaSyAeaWLxSHFEdwWEVVYajslt7R9eP0ZpLXQ',

            success : function(res)
            {
                // ParseFloat the <latitud> and <longitud>
                //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(trader.geo.lat),parseFloat(trader.geo.lon));

                initMap(res.results[0].geometry.location);
            },
            error : function(error)
            {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

        function initMap(oLatlng)
        {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center : oLatlng,
                zoom : 15
            });
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it worked thanks!! I still have problems lik that with JS, really thanks guy